# Is there a connection between cpu idle and cpu load?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-load

The higher load, the lower idle?Is there a situation that high load meanwhile high idle out there?

[image: a screen shot]

Comment: The very meaning of “load” (dictionary-wise) tells you it can never mean idle. I highly recommend you read the Wikipedia article on [Load (as in computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)).

Comment: @Daniel i know they're different.What i suspect is they're related.

Comment: Of course they’re related. They have opposing meanings. However, they measure different things, so they cannot be compared directly.

Comment: On macOS I can say for a fact that you can have high load (a lot more than 1 per core) and have fairly high cpu idle (>50%) at the same time. Seems very strange to me, but it can definitely happen.

Answer (score 3):

The two are directly related. `Load% + Idle% = 100%`.

That means when one increases, the other decreases. No exceptions.

Imagine a glass with water. The water + the remaining empty space totals the glass capacity. You cannot have more than 50% water and more than 50% free space in the glass at the same time.

Comment: From the Wikipedia I  noticed that load and idle measure different things.how to explain idle +load=100?

Comment: The 2 things are part of the same integer and directly related, just like in the glass example. Idle time actually measures unused CPU capacity, while load shows the used one.

Comment: I've updated a screen shot to specify the question.If they are directly related ,does it mean one can be caculated out according to another one's value?But I cannot see that.Thanks for ur time!

Answer (score 1):

From the Wikipedia [load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)) page you can see they are related, because:

> For single-CPU systems that are CPU bound, one can think of load
>   average as a percentage of system utilization during the respective
>   time period. For systems with multiple CPUs, one must divide the
>   number by the number of processors in order to get a comparable
>   percentage.

And the lengthier explanation about load tells you that:

> For example, one can interpret a load average of "1.73 0.60 7.98" on a
>   single-CPU system as:
>
> - during the last minute, the system was overloaded by 73% on average    (1.73 runnable processes, so that 0.73 processes had to wait for a
>     turn for a single CPU system on average).
> - during the last 5 minutes, the CPU was idling 40% of the time on average.
> - during the last 15 minutes, the system was overloaded 698% on average (7.98 runnable processes, so that 6.98 processes had to wait
>     for a turn for a single CPU system on average).

This will tell you that the load will point out the processor time necessary to execute all the waiting processes, thus, **the higher the load the less idle time you will have until that load reaches 0**.